# Nginx is throwing permission denied error

Tags: nginx

Nginx is throwing error when starting as

```
#service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] open() "/data/ems/log/nginx_log/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
```

After doing some randing thing, like changing permission etc, I'm able to start using

```
# nginx -p /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Question:
1. Although I'm starting nginx in both method as ROOT user, when starting through daemon process is not working.

2. How to make deamon to start the nginx properly?

OS: RHEL 6.7
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1

Comment: In your `nginx.conf` file there's usually a `user` directive. Does this user have read and write access to `/data/ems/log/nginx_log/error.log`?

Comment: yes, i've usedroot user for it.   `user root;`